# pscp "Cannot open file"

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, cp, pscp

I am trying to deploy the files in my web application to the server using the `pscp` tool. It works for all the files in the directory, except `sqlite (.db)` file.

For the `sqlite` file, it throws this error:

```
C:\Projects>pscp weblog.db user@host:/home/data

pscp: weblog.db: Cannot open file
```

The same command works for all the other files/directories.

**How do I copy the `.db` file for `sqlite` using `ssh/pscp`?**

Answer (score 0):

I had the database open in the [DB Browser for Sqlite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/), which was preventing the operation. Closing the application did the trick.